# Android emulator running on VirtualBox vs. real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

I've developed an Android application and I'm running it on a android virtual machine in order to get a faster execution of my application, but how can I compare the virtual emulator performances to those of a real device?

Thanks

Comment: in my experiences applications run on virtual machines are in general slower than on the real device.

Comment: This is a good news for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer may not be what your looking for. I dont think you can compare performance between an emulator and any real device. Firstly because your software isnt running on the target hardware. The emulator may be doing all sorts of additional things to make it look like that hardware. there will be layers of software running your software generally making your programme run slow.

The best thing you could do is do some performance profiling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713940/eclipse-java-profiler which would show you where bottle necks are and give you some idea of performance.

There's no real substitute for running on the target hardware. emulation will show you your software is functionally working but it may hide timing bugs it you have time critical code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately, as you said, this isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

the virtualbox is just an emulater. it wont carry out the application's full preformance, as it has to go through multiple layers of software. for testing out apps, a real android device is necassesary.